# How to get links of another workbook using Regex in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, regex

I have a bill folder containing all the bills, named as

> Bill No. Customer name

, if bill no is

> 36

and customer name is

> Star Enterprise

, Bill is named as

> 36 Star Enterprise.

I want to access the bill amount of all these customers in a different workbook automatically.

I can manually do this by this formula:

```
='R:\My Drive\Rahul Steels\Rahul Steels Bills 2022-23\[36 Star Enterprise.xlsm]ORIGINAL FOR RECEIPENT'!$M$39
```

What I want to do is any one of the following :

Access the M39 cell in workbook by only the Bill No. using regex ^ and drag this formula down, so that Bill No. automatically increases and the formula looks like this : -

```
='R:\My Drive\Rahul Steels\Rahul Steels Bills 2022-23\[^36.xlsm]ORIGINAL FOR RECEIPENT'!$M$39
```

Or

I Access the M39 cell in the workbook by manually writing the customer name in another column of same workbook and using &, which looks like this (assume customer name is written in E46) and drag this formula so that both bill no and customer row keeps on increasing ,i.e 37 and E47 in next column:-

```
='R:\My Drive\Rahul Steels\Rahul Steels Bills 2022-23\[36&E46.xlsm]ORIGINAL FOR RECEIPENT'!$M$39
```

Or

Any other simple way, if this is not possible so that I can access the final amount of every bill(M39 cell) without opening it and typing it manually.

Comment: No, it is a completely different problem.

Comment: You could use a formula to build the string that contains the bill no and customer name. Then your formula references that inside an INDIRECT function. (you can do all this in one formula, but I suggest building it in pieces first).
Or use PowerQuery to fetch the data from all of the files in the folder, as long as the value is in the same cell in every case. Start at Data > Get Data > From File > From folder

Comment: How can I use regex to get the file using just Bill No, assuming my Bill No is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being it is not possible to do any such thing in MS Excel, you have to manually enter the links or manually give the reference by opening another workbook by opening it.

Suppose if you have saved the files only as Bill no.s (instead of Bill no followed by customer name), then you might me (I don't know that it will surely work, I couldn't find any relevant solutions for this on internet) be able to drag the links, like the formula and some of your time might be saved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).